# Match the occurance of a pattern within a string and insert characters in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, typescript

For instance, assume we have a string `firstName=&lastName=&phoneNumber=&`. Now, we would like to match the pattern `lastname=` so that we can insert `bobson` into the space before the ampersand. Therefore, the final result would be `firstName=&lastName=bobson&phoneNumber=&`.

Comment: *Stack Overflow Wouldn't Be Very Welcoming*. Show your attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could search for the pattern and insert

```js
var string = 'firstName=&lastName=&phoneNumber=&',
    replacement = 'bobson';

console.log(string.replace(/lastName=/, '$&' + replacement));
```

For replacement, you could seach for the pattern and replace all between pattern and ampersand.

```js
var string = 'firstName=&lastName=xx&phoneNumber=&',
    replacement = 'bobson';

console.log(string.replace(/(lastName=)[^&]*/, '$1' + replacement));
```

Comment: Prefekt! Thank you very much!